# Combine text with categorical features using entity embeddings and Keras functional API

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, nlp, embedding

I'm trying to combine text and categorical variables using Keras functional API.

The model compiles but when I try to train the model using "fit", it gives me an error.
Looks like the way I put the data is wrong.
Has anyone ever done something similar and knows how to make it work?

Code for building the model:

```
all_inputs = []
cat_embeddings = []

text_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, ),name='text_input')
all_inputs.append(text_input)

x = Embedding(embedding_matrix.shape[0], # or len(word_index) + 1
              embedding_matrix.shape[1], # or EMBEDDING_DIM,
              weights=[embedding_matrix],
              input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
              trainable=True)(text_input)

x = SpatialDropout1D(0.2)(x)
x = Bidirectional(GRU(128, return_sequences=True,dropout=0.1,recurrent_dropout=0.1))(x)
x = Conv1D(64, kernel_size = 3, padding = "valid", kernel_initializer = "glorot_uniform")(x)
x = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

for cat in Categorical_Features:
    cat_input = Input(shape=(1,), name=cat)
    no_of_unique_cat  = X_train[cat].nunique()
    embedding_size = np.ceil((no_of_unique_cat)/2)
    embedding_size = int(embedding_size)
    cat_embedding = Embedding(no_of_unique_cat+1, embedding_size, input_length = 1)(cat_input)
    cat_embedding = Reshape(target_shape=(embedding_size,))(cat_embedding)

    all_inputs.append(cat_input)
    cat_embeddings.append(cat_embedding)

conc = Concatenate()(cat_embeddings)
x = concatenate([conc, x])

x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)

preds = Dense(93, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = Model(inputs=all_inputs, outputs=preds)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Then I try to put the data in this way:

```
model.fit([X_train_seq,
           X_train['Categorical_Features_1'],
           X_train['Categorical_Features_2'],
           X_train['Categorical_Features_3'],
           X_train['Categorical_Features_4'],
           X_train['Categorical_Features_5'],
           X_train['Categorical_Features_6']]
          ,
          y_train, 
          validation_split=0.2, 
          class_weight = d_class_weights,
          epochs=5, 
          batch_size=512)
```

Then I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[460,0] = 421 is not in [0, 406)
     [[{{node embedding_18/GatherV2}} = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@training_8/Adam/gradients/embedding_18/GatherV2_grad/Reshape"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_18/embeddings/read, embedding_18/Cast, embedding_17/GatherV2/axis)]]
```

This code is inspired by the code in this Kaggle competition:

https://www.kaggle.com/aquatic/entity-embedding-neural-net

and the paper "Entity Embeddings of Categorical Variables":

https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06737

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `Embedding` layer whereby your `len(word_index) + 1` or `embedding_matrix.shape[0]` doesn't actually correspond to the maximum index. In this case `len(word_index) + 1 = 407` but your first input integer index is actually `421` which is out of bounds.

You need to double check the `X_train_seq` indices and whether they are within the range provided to the `Embedding` layer.

Comment: This does not seem to be the problem.
I tried to run the model without the categories embeddings and it worked.
So I guess I'm putting the data wrong or I'm building the categories embeddings wrong.

Comment: Maybe the indexes in the categorical features are partially vacant, which makes the number of unique categories not match the max index. In that case I think you should use `X_train[cat].max()` instead of `X_train[cat].nunique()` when creating the categorical feature embedding layers, or remove the vacant category in the data and re-index them with new indexes.